# How to link 2 outlook meetings?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, meetings

How can you link 2 meetings in outlook? 
Is it possible to automatically cancel one meeting when another gets cancelled?

My team has a recurring meeting set from 2 to 5. The team is distributed in different locations.

I would like to create a local meeting from 1:30 to 5, to reserve a conference room and have time to setup the equipment.

Is there a way I could link the local meeting from 1:30 to 5 with the meeting from 2 to 5, so if the Team Leader cancels or reschedules the later, mine would get moved also?

We have these meetings frequently, and I would like to minimize manual setup hassle as much as possible.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no method to handle this.

Comment: @Zoredache thanks! I certainly couldn't find a way to do it. I was hoping there was one though.